# Nativescript 6.x project using Xcode 12. Will Xcode 13 work?

Tags: xcode, nativescript, xcode12, xcode13

I've got a NS 6.x project.

I can build it using Xcode 12.

If I download Xcode 13 (for iOS 15 testing), will it build the same NS 6.x project - without breaking it, requiring ns/plugin updates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't tried already, I have been able to compile an app using NS 6.8.0 on Xcode 13.  A couple of points:

1. At first it seemed to fail building, but it does now work.  I think the solution was to remove my platforms folder but I can't confirm if this is the actual fix.
2. My app now seems to be affected by a transparent status bar at the top of the app.  When you start to scroll the page the colour fills in, but I am still trying to find a solution for this.

I hope that helps!?

Comment: I have a 6.8 project, just updated to Xcode 13, and am seeing the transparent status bar as well.  I'd welcome any solution.

Comment: My solution unfortunately was to downgrade XCode.  The nav bar seems to be part of a new UI being pushed by Apple - [this link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420) might be able to help provide a bit more context to why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the transparent status bar, I was able to hack out this code and get it working:

in main-page.js:

```
const Color = require("tns-core-modules/color").Color
const Frame = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame").Frame;
const platform = require("tns-core-modules/platform");
```

in onNavigatingTo

```
  let osVersionMajor = platform.device.osVersion.split(".")[0];
  if (platform.isIOS && osVersionMajor >= 15 ) {
    let navigationBar = Frame.topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
    let appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground();
    appearance.backgroundColor = new Color("#FF2525FE").ios;
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary({
      [NSForegroundColorAttributeName]: UIColor.whiteColor
    });
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance;
  }
```

This matches the blue title bar in the blue theme, but you could change the  hex code for the background color to whatever you want.  Also note, this is a NativeScript 6.8 JavaScript project.